# Magento change database query collation

Tags: mysql, magento

I have a `Magento 1.5.1.0` installation, and some of the products in the catalog has swedish characters at the start of the product name. This causes an incorrect sort when sorting by name. Ä and Å becomes A, and Ö becomes O.

This means the sorting will be like:

```
A
Å
Ä
B
[...]
```

This is because the database is using the collation `utf8_general_ci`. I've found you can override what collation MySQL uses when executing a query, but I just can not find a good way to get it into the Magento code. Should this perhaps be done on the Zend level?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `\app\etc\local.xml`, find `default_setup` section and add `<initStatements>` tag with your query there (or change if it is already present). So, it will look like:

```
<default_setup>
    <connection>
        <host><![CDATA[your_host]]></host>
        <username><![CDATA[user]]></username>
        <password><![CDATA[password]]></password>
        <dbname><![CDATA[db]]></dbname>
        <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci']]></initStatements>
        <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
        <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
        <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
        <active>1</active>
    </connection>
</default_setup>
```

Comment: I've tried this with the same result. Tried restarting MySQL and clearing all caches as well.

Comment: Stupid question, but have you converted your database collation from `utf8_general_ci` to `utf8_unicode_ci`?

Comment: Just tried that on our development server, `ALTER DATABASE  <db_name> DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Hmm, can you try run simple query with order by this field with swedish characters in your phpmyadmin (or another gui for db)? Does the sorting by this field work right at all?

Comment: I ran this query `SELECT lower(substring(value,1,1)) as first_char,value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar HAVING first_char='a' ORDER BY value` and it found both `a` and `ä`. But if I run the query like this `SELECT lower(substring(value,1,1)) as first_char,value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar HAVING first_char='a' ORDER BY value COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci` it doesn't find any results with `ä`. I appreciate your help Zyava.